# Toggle functionality in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So at the beginning I know this code is messy. I have a div that I wanna copy, when I click on the div, it opens up a Content and it copies that div. The thing I can't seem to accomplish is this, In that copied version of div/Image, I want to have a toggle functionality as in a regular one. If you don't fully understand it here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bassi-ogzjq. Thank you

```
const data= [
{
  id:1,
  img:"./images/icons/folder.png",
  name:"Small Projects"
}
]

function App() {
 
  const [isProjectOpen, setIsProjectOpen] = useState(false)
  const project= useRef(null)
  const [smallProject, setSmallProject] =useState()
  const [active, setActive] = useState()
  
  const closeProject = () =>{
    setIsProjectOpen(false)
  }
  
 

  const proj = data.find(projects => projects.id===smallProject)

  const handleProject=(e)=>{
    if(project.current && !project.current.contains(e.target)){
      closeProject() 
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('click', handleProject)
    return() =>{
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleProject)
    }
  },[])
  return (

    <>
     
      {data.map((projects)=>{           
        return(
          <>
           {active === project.id && (
            <div
               onClick={()=>setIsProjectOpen(!isProjectOpen)}
               className='smallProject__container'
               key={projects.id}
               ref={project}   >        
            <img 
               onClick={()=>setSmallProject(projects.id)}  
               className="smallProject__img"           
               src={projects.img}/> 
            <h4 
               onClick={()=>setSmallProject(projects.id)}
              >{projects.name} </h4>
               {isProjectOpen ? <SmallProject /> :null}  
            </div>)}  
           </>   
             )  
             })}     
            {smallProject && (       
           <div
             onClick={()=>setIsProjectOpen(!isProjectOpen)}
             className={"smallProjects__container " + ((isProjectOpen) ? "active": "")} >
          <img
            classsName='copy__img'
            src={proj.img}/>
            </div>
             )}       
    </>     
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's not clear which div you're trying to copy and what toggle functionality you're trying to preserve.

Comment: I want to have toggle functionality in that copied div

Comment: @codemonkey when I press that copied div I want to open/close Small Project component

Comment: So when you click the `Lock project` button, you want the tiny project part on the right to show/hide right? Click - show, click again - hide?

Comment: wow the sandbox is broken

Comment: @AjeetShah Shah its not

Comment: @AjeetShah this one is working https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lake-uovir?file=/src/SmallProject.js

Comment: "This one is working" : does it mean that you have solved your problem? I am still not able to understand your requirement.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah when I press on the copied div it closes the component, but when I try to open the component via copied div it's not working